# Need to set path as a system property for java project

Tags: java, eclipse, system-variable

I have 2 property files which are part of my java eclipse project. Now i need to pass the path of these 2 files as a system property like `-Dpath1="pathfile1"` as project will only accept it as a system property.
One option is that i can specify the absolute path but i want to specify a path relative to my project something like `-Dpath1=$Project_Dir/resource/file1`. Reason being, if project directory is moved then project will start failing.

I am using eclipse to run this project and dont want to declare any new system variable for supporting relative path, so for example dont want to create a new system variable `Project_Dir` . Is it possible to achieve this and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set system properties with:

```
System.setProperty("path1", yourPathHere);
```

Now, you only have to build the correct path, relative to where your project is. To do this, start off with the location of the project: [How to get the path of a running JAR file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file)

Answer (score 1):

When using `setProperty`, you can reference internal project files if you use a plain relative path.

E.g. to reference a file located at /abc/def/workspace/project/lib/driver.exe:

`System.setProperty("driver", "lib/driver.exe");`

It's deceivingly simple.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it.Eclipse have build-in Path variable PROJECT_LOC, it stores location of project folder, e.x. c:\Workspace\Project1.
You can use this property in launch configuration.